# Data.Text constants in Haskell

Tags: string, haskell, text, compiler-errors

In the documentation of Data.Text, there are examples such as `replace "oo" "foo" "oo"`. However, when I try to run this, it tells me that the function replace was expecting Text, but got String. Now, of course, I could use `pack` in front of every constant to turn the Strings into type Text, but that is rather inconvenient. Is there a way to write text constants the way they do in the documentation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The documentation of `Data.Text` has for all examples the [**`OverloadedStrings`**](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-OverloadedStrings) extension enabled. This will, for all string literals, add an implicit `fromString` function call.

For example:

```
$ ghci -XOverloadedStrings
GHCi, version 8.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded GHCi configuration from /home/kommusoft/.ghc/ghci.conf
Prelude> import Data.Text
Prelude Data.Text> replace "oo" "foo" "oo"
"foo"
```

or you can add this as a pragma in your Haskell file:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Text

foo = replace "oo" "foo" "oo"
```

By using `OverloadedString`s you can make your own type that works with string *literals*. For example you can make a type:

```
import Data.String

newtype SpecialString = SpecialString String

instance IsString SpecialString where
    fromString = SpecialString
```

Now you can use string literal, and these can, depending on the context, get converted to a `SpecialString`.

Answer (score 2):

I checked the documentation and you're right - this will only work if you are using the [OverloadedStrings](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#overloaded-string-literals) GHC extension.

It allows you to use string literals for other "string-like" types, and is pretty much a necessity if you're working heavily with `Text` or `ByteString`. I am surprised that it does not appear to be mentioned in the documentation, but it is clearly assumed that `OverloadedStrings` is in use in these examples.